# How to prevent others from accessing your Solana program?

Tags: solana

Let's say for example I built a personal token program.

I want to be the only one that can access it and change its state. What's the best practice for this?

Do I hardcode my public key in the code and do if() checks on the transaction's public key?

Or

Do I have some initialize() function that modifies a struct in my program and sets the caller as the owner of the program?

Also

Is it okay to hardcode some constant values in my program?

Let's say it's not changing anyway like:
const price: f32 = 1.50;

Since it's not changing is it okay to add it directly on the code no need to add it in structs for serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to lock down the program is to hard-code certain pubkeys that must be signers in an instruction to use it.  For example, every instruction checks that "XXXX" is a signer, where "XXXX" is your wallet. Otherwise, anyone can use it.

As a consideration, you could keep it open, but allow people to create their own state / accounts, and then every other instruction must be signed by that owner.